# Is there anyway to let WebStorm understand the aliases in .eslinrc made using eslint-import-resolver-alias

Tags: webstorm, eslint

In my project, I used *eslint-import-resolver-alias* for imports like below in .eslintrc:

```
{
  "settings":{
    "alias": [
      ["pckg", "pckg/src"]
    ]
  }
}
```

And I use as below in my .js files

```
import pckg from 'pckg'
```

But when I try to find the declaration using a Cmd+Click by clicking on '*pckg*' in the import statement, WebStorm says that there is no declaration to go to. I realize that WebStorm is not able to understand the import alias resolver plugin, but is there anyway to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using webpack aliases instead: create a dummy webpack configuration file with aliases like

```
...
alias: {
  'pckg': path.resolve(__dirname, './pckg/src'),
},
...
```

and specify a path to it in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack**, or use a workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22717#focus=streamItem-27-1558931-0-0:

- create a file `config.js` (you can use a different name if you like) in your project root dir
- define your aliases there using the following syntax:

```
    System.config({
      "paths": {
         "pckg/*": "./pckg/src/*"
      }
    });
```